# Without double-clocking, how to perform 2 write and 2 read each clock using Dual Port RAM?

Tags: sram

In a project I'm working currently, the quad-port RAM ,which can perform 2 write and 2 read each clock by double-clocking technique, is required to achieve some specific goals. But now it seems too hard to meet the timing, because after the double-clocking, the quad-port RAM must run at a frequency over 1GHz. Is there any way to achieve the same performance as quad-port RAM using dual port RAM ? And the same performance can be achieved without double-clocking ?

Comment: Is this in an FPGA? Could you give a part number / datasheet and some more context please? Also, can you separate the two write sources - is it really an any-to-any read/write operation?

Comment: Not enough information. Any relationships between addresses on each of your four ports may help to achieve a good solution : e.g. reads and writes from the same address; writes guaranteed to be odd/even, (or lower/upper half of memory) etc. Are there any such relationships or are all four addresses completely uncorrelated?

Comment: @pjc50, I don't know any FPGA that has quad port RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Basically You need to double the bus width if doubling the clock rate is not a solution. Consider changing hardware.